# flutter problem: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, stripe-payments, flutter-test, flutter-stripe

this is my flutter stripe code,
Here I want response of SetupPaymentSheetParameters and presentPaymentSheet
I want to check what king of response I am getting,

```
Future<void> makePayment(data) async {
    print(data['clientSecret']);
  try {
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
              paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: "${data['clientSecret']}",
            style: ThemeMode.dark,
          ))
          .then((value) {});

      ///now finally display payment sheeet
    displayPaymentSheet();
  } catch (e, s) {
    print('exception:$e$s');
  }
}

displayPaymentSheet() async {
  try {
    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
    ).then((value){
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green,),
                    Text("Payment Successfull"),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ));
      // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("paid successfully")));
    }).onError((error, stackTrace){
      print('Error is:--->$error $stackTrace');
    });
  } on StripeException catch (e) {
    print('Error is:---> $e');
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => const AlertDialog(
          content: Text("Cancelled "),
        ));
  } catch (e) {
    print('$e');
  }
}
```

Here I getting something like this is happening I dont know.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

> return type of **SetupPaymentSheetParameters** should be Future

change your print method to this :

```
print(value.toString());
```

hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

For help with the `flutter_stripe` package you'll want to reach out to the developers to get better explanations.

However, it looks like your `value` is actually attached to the result of `initPaymentSheet`, which is [void](https://pub.dev/documentation/stripe_platform_interface/latest/stripe_platform_interface/StripePlatform/initPaymentSheet.html). [SetupPaymentSheetParameters](https://pub.dev/documentation/stripe_platform_interface/latest/stripe_platform_interface/SetupPaymentSheetParameters/SetupPaymentSheetParameters.html) should return json data for use with `initPaymentSheet`.